# Convert string '201405' to May 2014

Tags: php, datetime, datepicker

I am using a plugin that's returning a string like this 201405. I would like to echo it out as May 2014. How can I do this in php.

I don't need to convert it to a date type but that's a bonus.

Thanks

Comment: www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Thanks, I read through that page and the other linked pages and found it a bit overwhelming which is why am asking for help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$date = new DateTime('201405');
$result = $date->format('F Y');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = '201405';
$english_date = date('F Y', strtotime($string.'00'));
```